# How to structure a Vue3 - Vue Router 4 app with a custom hash separator (not #) inside an PHP environment

Tags: php, vuejs3, vue-router

I have to build an app with Vue3 and VueRouter inside a php app where there is already a (strange) hash navigation system.

Now, the navigation system of the app in php looks like this (and unfortunatelly I cannot change that):
app.com/#eyJnZXQiOlDdLCJwb3N0IjpbXSwicCFnZSI6IlwvaW5jXC93awRnZXRcL3dpZGdldC5waHAifQ==.

And as you can see, it is a random hash of tot characters.

I would like to build an app in Vue3 and with VueRouter4 so that my navigation starts after that hash, ie:

app.com/#eyJnZXQiOlDdLCJwb3N0IjpbXSwicCFnZSI6IlwvaW5jXC93awRnZXRcL3dpZGdldC5waHAifQ==/my-new-app/etc

I know that VueRouter4 uses "#" as a separator and as the main character to figure out how to work, but unfortunately for me it is already present in the app hash in php, so he gets confused.

Could you advise me on the best method to be able to make my app and use VueRouter4 without any problems by starting at the end of the php hash?

Thanks for any useful information

Comment: how did you manage to read the fragment/hash from the current url in php?

Comment: I don't know, it was a technical chioce of a previous developer to put that hash (i think to badly offuscate the path).